# Error message - unable to connect to tracking_contact on a CD server

Tags: mongodb

I have a Sitecore 8.1 instance that was upgraded from v7.5.  We are using hosted Mongo at ObjectRocket.  I don't remember during the upgrade process any step that told me I was supposed to add a connection string for the tracking_contact database in Mongo.  Now I am getting the following error in my log files:

> ManagedPoolThread #4 13:43:59 ERROR Unable to connect to server
>   iad1-mongos0.objectrocket.com:12345: Invalid credential for database
>   'tracking_contact'..

Plus when I look in my Mongo db hosted at ObjectRocket I don't even see any tracking_contact database.  Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a connection string named `tracking.contact` in your `ConnectionStrings.config`?

Comment: I didn't originally.  Then I saw the errors and I added one.  I was assuming that somehow magically the system would create the necessary collections in Mongo.  But it didn't.

Comment: I also manually added the tracking_content database to our Mongo instance.  But that didn't help either.

Comment: Make sure that you have these in your `connectionstrings.config` file: `<add name="analytics" connectionString="mongodb://localhost/analytics" />
  <add name="tracking.live" connectionString="mongodb://localhost/tracking_live"/>
  <add name="tracking.history" connectionString="mongodb://localhost/tracking_history"/>
  <add name="tracking.contact" connectionString="mongodb://localhost/tracking_contact"/>` and also after these changes make sure to reset IIS.. Sitecore should automatically create them.

Comment: Vamshi - I would assume that your Mongo user would need proper access to create databases right? We are using hosted Mongo at ObjectRocket and I believe they only give us database access, not full Mongo admin access.  I wonder if that could be the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the answer.  Embarrassingly enough the answer is that the user I created in the Mongo db was named incorrectly.  Once I renamed it, everything worked properly and Sitecore created the necessary collections.